# Compile time enforcement of length equality for a runtime list

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

Suppose I have a runtime list of numbers `Int`, the *length of which I do not know at compile time*, e.g.

`numbers: Seq[Int]`.

I also have function that takes an `Int` element and returns an `A`, e.g.

`f: Int => A`

I have another function that takes an `Int` element and returns a `B`, e.g.

`g: Int => B`

If I map over the list with `f` and `g` separately, I end up with 2 lists:

```
val list1: Seq[A] = numbers.map(f)
val list2: Seq[B] = numbers.map(g)
```

Is there any way for me to write a function that works with these two lists and ensures at compile that the number of elements in both are the same?

Since both `list1` and `list2` are `map`ed from the same list (`numbers`), I'm thinking it might be possible using Shapeless' `Sized`, but I couldn't figure out how to do it without knowledge of `numbers`'s length at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

A low tech solution to this problem would be to avoid creating two separate lists in the first place,

```
val list12: Seq[(A, B)] = numbers.map { i => (f(i), g(i)) }
```

I recommend exploring this avenue before deploying heavy artillery.

Comment: Thanks for answering; however I'm should clarify that this example is a simplified version of what I'm currently trying to accomplish, which is to transform a sequence of data into a Chart data structure with a sequence of headers and a sequence of rows which are a sequence of cells; what I would like to do make sure that the header length is the same as the length of each row. Both headers and rows are generated from the same input data, but I would like to only generate the headers *once*, as opposed to doing again and again on a per-row basis.

Comment: Have you seen the header/row example [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala)?

Comment: Yup, I've looked into that example in detail, but both cases (static and mixed) require me to know the lengths beforehand :( In my case, the headers and row length are completely unknown to me at compile time, but I want to ensure they're the same by referring to a runtime length identifier (e.g. `someData.size`).  For the moment, I've given up and just used a runtime check that results in an error message wrapped in an Either.